# Covariance between functions of identically distributed random variables

Tags: measure-theory, statistics, covariance

Let $\{X_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of random variables identically distributed as $X$, possibly dependent, and $f$ be a measurable function.

I'm trying to show that in general $Cov(f(X_i),f(X_j))\neq Cov(f(X_1),f(X_2)),\forall i\neq j$.

**Question**: How would you argue that $Cov(f(X_i),f(X_j))= Cov(f(X_1),f(X_2)),\forall i\neq j,$ is false?

**Comments**: $Cov(X_i,X_j)$ can vary depending on the indices $i,j$, and these covariances seem to affect, somehow, their respective $Cov(f(X_i),f(X_j))$, which should also vary according to $i,j$. From this idea,  $Cov(f(X_i),f(X_j))= Cov(f(X_1),f(X_2)),\forall i\neq j,$ would be impossible. That is, if all covariaces $Cov(X_i,X_j), i\neq j,$ are not the same, how could all $Cov(f(X_i),f(X_j))$ be the same? Unfortunately, I cannot formalize this argument. Can you help me?

Comment: Except a few trivial cases (e.g. $f$ is a constant function or $f(\xi) = a \xi + b$), the covariances of the $Z_k = f(X_k)$ will not be readily available even if we know all the covariances between the different $X_k.$

Comment: If $\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)\neq 0$ you can just take $f=0$.

Comment: @WilliamM. Are you saying that I should consider $f$ case by case? If yes, I will ask another related question with a specific function $f$.

Comment: If you want $\mathbf{Cov}(f(x), f(y))$ then you should calculate it by force unless $f$ is a line in which case you can use bilinearity of the covariance. If you only want to bound $|\mathbf{Cov}(f(x), f(y))|,$ then you can use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and this will require you to calculate $\mathbf{Var}(f(x))$ and $\mathbf{Var}(f(y)).$

Comment: @WilliamM. Can you take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4639192/covariance-between-random-variables-for-identically-distributed-data-2